# namespace prefix not declared basex

Tags: module, namespaces, xquery, basex

I'm trying to use a module that I have imported into Basex database engine.
The module can be found here : https://git.unistra.fr/estrades/heimdall

I have done what they said to import the module in basex with the following command

```
REPO INSTALL https://estrades.pages.unistra.fr/heimdall/heimdall.xar
```

and then i opened basexgui.

Then I wrote my xQuery file like this :

```
let $doc := doc('zotero/zotero.xml')
let $result := heimdall:getDatabaseItems('db')
return $result
```

And I got this error message :

```
Namespace prefix not declared: heimdall
```

I suppose that I have to declare or import my module at the begining probably someway like this :

```
import module namespace heimdall = 'https://estrades.pages.unistra.fr/heimdall/heimdall.xar';
```

but it is not working.

I think I misunderstand the concept of declared modules. I don't see the meaning of calling my module in my xQuery file if I have imported it earlier directly in BaseX...

Someone could help me maybe ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You will indeed need to add an import statement for your module in the prolog of your query. However, the URI must match the namespace of your module, which you can look up in the [expath-pkg.xml](https://git.unistra.fr/estrades/heimdall/-/blob/main/expath-pkg.xml) file or the [haimdall.xqm](https://git.unistra.fr/estrades/heimdall/-/blob/main/src/heimdall.xqm) module itself.

This should work:

```
import module namespace heimdall = 'http://estrades.huma-num.fr/heimdall';

let $doc := doc('zotero/zotero.xml')
let $result := heimdall:getDatabaseItems('db')
return $result
```